# convert a complicated text to date format in ms excel 2007

Tags: excel-2007

I have text in the following (many lines):
*May 1, 2014, 11:26 am ,second:51*
Any ideas to convert it to recognize-able (and can be ordered) like:
*yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss* would be nice if I can have another column describing the day (e.g. monday-sunday).
Really appreciate you help. Best regards, Ben

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question whether the month is abbreviated of written in full. May is a bad example. It is also not clear if single digit hours will have a leading zero. Next time, please provide a bigger data sample.

My suggestion is this formula to create a date/time value that can be formatted and sorted.

```
=DATE(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,4)+0,MATCH(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"},0),MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)-2,2)+0)+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)-2,8))+TIME(0,0,RIGHT(A1,2))+0
```

Format the result with any format you prefer. The screenshot has custom format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

[image]